# Cache data is custom hook - prevent rerender

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-hooks, memoization, react-memo

I have a custom hook which fetches some basic user profile data from my graphql server. It is called from a number of components to access that data. Right now it seems like it is causing rerenders, because it fetches that data again, each time it is called. How should I best cache this data within this hook? `useCustomQuery` is imported from my gql client.

```
export const useUserData = () => {

  const { data, isLoading, error } = useCustomQuery({
    query: async (query) => {
      return getFields(query.me, 'account_id', 'role', 'email', 'profile_image');
    },
  });
  return { isLoading, error, me: data };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at where you are calling your custom hook (in a useEffect maybe?), and try to incorporate useMemo to memoize the data coming back until you need to actually call that custom hook again.

But, without further code, it's a bit difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score -1):

A custom React Hook is a way to abstract a piece of stateful logic and every component that ends up calling this hook gets a separate instance of the hook along with a separate isolated state.

**For Example:**

If you call `useUserData` from:

- `UserProfile` component and
- `UserAccountSettings` component

Both of them would call `useUserData` and none of them would be aware that the other component already performed a fetch using this hook.

And if `useUserData` had an internal state then, both of the `useUserData` invocations (one from `UserProfile` and the other from `UserAccountSettings`) would end up getting a separate and independent state.

## What if you want to maintain a cache?

Yes, you can do that. You just need to store `data` returned from the GraphQL server in an external scope like a Redux Store, a Global Context or even a parent component's state.

But, you **should not** handle this `storing/caching` logic in `useUserData` instead, it needs to be abstracted out. Perhaps, [it can be part of the handler making the request to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313364/react-how-optimize-a-custom-hook-that-shares-data).

### Why can't the hook be responsible for caching?

A hook can be responsible for it and you can take an approach where you maintain a cache by defining a variable in the scope external to the hook's lifecycle.

It will still work.
In the end, it depends upon your coding pattern and the level of abstraction you want.

### Why can't UserProfile or UserAccountSettings perform the cache check?

Because that would lead to a conditional check and hence, a conditional call to the `useUserData` and a React hook should not be called conditionally.

### Resources

- [Building your own Hooks](https://17.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook)

  - Question to look: Do two components using the same Hook share state?
  - Question to look: How does a custom Hook get isolated state?
- [Another answer describing the caching process by maintaining a variable in an external scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313364/react-how-optimize-a-custom-hook-that-shares-data)